# How to connect single.c/.h files to cmake project?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, cmake

So, I'm new to cmake and have some troubles. I have simple cmake project that contains a few .h and .c files. I've searched C code at github which consists of only one .h and one .c files. And i want to use some functions from this pack, but i don't want to put this file in my project directory. I want to keep them somewhere outside the project directory. So, how to connect them to project, how to make header visible for project and use #include "name.h" for watching and 
and using available C functions .c/.h pack in my project.

Comment: There are already several solutions posted on Stack Overflow about how to include an external project (from Github) in your own CMake project. Your question is pretty generic, so can you show what you have tried so far? Please provide some example code, and include any **specific** error messages or undesired behavior you might be observing.

Comment: I don't even know how to explain. I created C project in clion under cmake. It works pretty, but i wanted to expand some functionality just with a few functions that i've searched on GitHub(It was simple .h and .c file and nothing else) And i don't know how to use functionality from this .c/.h files not placing them into project folder. Just holding them somewhere ../projectFolder

Answer (score 0):

Create some other directory in your project, such as misc/ and put the files there. Then use it in your code via "/misc/name.h"

Comment: And is it possible to put them out of project folder and use them whit no problems. I've tried so much commands include_directories/ target/ link, i don't understand why it's o hard just to connect to files to the project from another location

Comment: To be honest I'm not quite sure, maybe it's possible to qualify it with (in respect to your project directory) by moving up the tree of directories with .. like in "../../someotherfolder/name.h"

Comment: @Sparkll It would be best if you could edit your question and add exactly what you tried. It might be easier to solve from there.